# Is it possible to identify what is blocking an await?

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, async-await, azure-web-app-service, profiling

I've got an intermittent problem on our application (.net core, mongo database and hosted with Azure).

Occasionally requests appear to get stuck.  A profiler trace using application insights shows this:

[image]

So the application is being held at an await for 17 seconds, before running the query for 63ms.

Is it possible, or is there a technique for finding out why it's hanging there and what's blocking it?   (note, I'm not asking specifically why it's hanging at this point...but how to find out)

Comment: If you get a memory dump at the time of the hang, you'll know what's hanging it.

Comment: It might be that something else is consuming CPU as well.